# AWK: field separator as '\x01'

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I have a File with below content like below

```
123\x01abc\x01bcd\x01\123
```

I tried using below two commands in bash:

```
echo "123\x01abc\x01bcd\x01\123" | awk -F'\\x01' '{print $1}'    
echo "123\x01abc\x01bcd\x01\123" | awk -F $'\x01' '{print $1}'  
echo "123\x01abc\x01bcd\x01\123" | awk -F\\x01' '{print $1}'
```

But all of them producing below output:

```
123\x01abc\x01bcd\x01\123
```

When tried with below command:

```
echo "123\x01abc\x01bcd\x01\123" | awk -F\x01' '{print $1}'
```

Above command giving below output, instead of 123:

```
123\
```

I want output as '\x01' separated fields. When I search AWK treating \x as hex and so, is AWK
expecting to pass hex as field separator after \x?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you read the accepted answer there carefully? you need `-F'\\\\x01'`

Comment: Got it.. Thanks! previously haven't tried all things mentioned in that ans